# left out join returns the duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables where i have to join and get the latest data. The 3 tables are as follows "STUDENT", "MATH", "ENGLISH".

### STUNDET tables contain:

```
ID  NAME  CLASS   CODE  MODIFIED_DATE
-------------------------------------
1   ABC   First   1234  01-10-2020
2   EFG   Second  3421  01-01-2020
3   XYZ   Third   1434  01-01-2020
1   ABC   First   9999  01-01-2021
```

### MATH table contain:

```
ID  MSCORE  MDATE
----------------
1    80  20-09-2020  
2    71  10-12-2020
1    74  04-03-2021
2    90  13-03-2020
```

### ENGLISH table contains:

```
ID  ESCORE  EDATE
---------------
 1   72  21-04-2021
 2   43  19-01-2021
 3   60  01-01-2021
 3   38  01-05-2021
```

### Result should be:

```
ID  NAME  CODE  MSCORE    MDATE      ESCORE  EDATE
----------------------------------------------
1   ABC   9999   74     04-03-2021    72    21-04-2021
2   EFG          71     10-12-2020    43    19-01-2021
3   XYZ                               38    01-05-2021
```

But i am getting duplicate records for each ID. when i am using the below query.

```
 select a.ID,a.NAME,a.CODE,b.MSCORE,b.MDATE,c.ESCORE,c.EDATE from STUDENT a LEFT OUTER JOIN MATH b ON a.ID=b.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN ENGLISH c ON a.ID=c.ID;
```

Please someone let me know what might be the correct query to fetch each record for a ID form tables based on the latest date given in MATH and ENGLISH table.

## EDIT:

I have added Code column to STUDENT table, and when i run the query i should get the latest code data for the ID.

Comment: Removed conflicting pl/sql and mysql tags as mysql does not support pl/sql. Pls confirm what database product you use.

Comment: Figure out which RDBMS you're using, and see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: oracle and mysql are different database products. Given the fact that you used pl/sql tags before, I must assume that you are using oracle. Removed the mysql tag. If my assumption was incorrect, pls correct the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the most recent row from each table, use window functions:

```
select s.*, m.MSCORE, m.MDATE, e.ESCORE, e.EDATE
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by s.id order by modified_date desc) as seqnum
      from STUDENT s
     ) s LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by m.id order by m.mdate desc) as seqnum
      from MATH m
     ) m
     on m.ID = s.ID and m.seqnum = 1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by e.id order by e.edate desc) as seqnum
      from ENGLISH e
     ) e
     on e.id = s.id and e.seqnum = 1
where s.seqnum = 1;
```

Note that I have replaced your *meaningless* table aliases with abbreviations for the table names.  This makes the query much simpler to read and maintain.

Comment: Your query is fetching the single records, Can you pls also see my new edit where i have added a new column "CODE' in Student table and whenever i run the query i should get the latest record from that table also, As currently i am getting 2 records from STUDENT table

Comment: Don't you have to do the same transformation to Student table too?  It has two occurrences of ID 1.

Comment: Chris, I have added that column later after Gordon gave the solution. Can you please add the query party for the student table occurance

Comment: @khajaaminulhussain . . . It is pretty much the same idea.

Comment: Looks Good ! Thanks for the solution Gordon

Answer (score 0):

A second way to do this is to use a correlated sub-query on each table before joining them to pick latest record for each ID:

```
Select s.id, s.name, s.code,m.mscore,m.MDATE, e.ESCORE, e.EDATE
From
     (Select * from Student s1
       Where modified_date=(Select max(modified_date 
                            From Student s2
                            Where s2.id=s1.id)
     ) s LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (Select * from Math m1
       Where mdate=(Select max(mdate)
                    From Math m2
                    Where m2.id=m1.id)
     ) m ON s.id=m.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (Select * from English e1
      Where edate=(Select max(edate)
                   From English e2
                   Where e2.id=e1.id)
     ) e ON s.id=e.id
```

Also, you should really make your 3 modified dates into date-time data types to distinguish among different modifications done the same day.  If two such records appear in your tables, this query fails by bringing back both records while Gordon Linoff answer could return a row that was not the most recent.

Comment: Thanks Chris, This looks simple for a non sql coder, I will try this out once and let you know

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add join criteria.  Fixed it now.